# how to change the size of a text inside a button using CSS ?? ( iam totally new on this)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, plugins

I'm making some adjustments to my WordPress page. I added a Plugin for customers to be redirected to my WhatsApp, but I want to configure the size of the button.

I was already able to change the size of the icon and the box itself, but I can't change the size of the text inside the box.

I don't know anything about HTML or CSS. I used Google to little by little make the adjustments mentioned. But I can't figure out how to change the size of the text inside the box.

i attached the link to my page: https://leotechpty.com/product/motherboard-msi-b560m-pro-e-proseries-matx-11va-10ma-gen-intel-core-lga-1200-socket-ddr4-pcie-4-m-2-slot-usb-3-2-gbps-lan/

What i want to change is the size of the text that says" Comprar en WhatsApp"

I clicked on inspect element but I don't know how much of the CSS code I should paste here. For this reason I only left the link to my website

use inspect element and google to adjust other parameters of interest to me but what I cannot modify (with my zero knowledge of the subject) is the size of the text inside the button

Answer (score 0):

You can change both properties:

```css
.button {
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 500px; /* it accept percentage and other values */
}
```

I recommend read [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp) to learn more about it.